# Css sprite alignment

Tags: html, css

I created a sprite image and css code:

```
.germany,.england{display: inline-block;background:url(/sprite-home.png) no-repeat;}
.germany{background-position:0 0;width:18px;height:13px;}
.england{background-position:-19px 0;width:18px;height:13px;}
```

and html

```
<a href="#" class="germany">Germany country</a>
```

But displays

[image: http://s24.postimg.org/ba867ryc1/image.png]

How display inline?

[image: https://s12.postimg.org/wzeys64v1/image.png]

**Upload:** https://jsfiddle.net/hrwk6fu9/

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or use SO snippet? It might be because you need to text-indent then set a with to a certain width.

Comment: Remove the `germany` class from the `a` tag and create a `span` inside the link. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/press/mf79rb2u/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hrwk6fu9/7/ Here is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/hrwk6fu9/4/)**

**CSS**

```
.germany:before, .england:before {
    background:url(http://s16.postimg.org/i9wm45sc1/sprite_home.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    text-indent: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width:18px;
    height:13px;
}
.germany:before {
    background-position:0 0;
}
.england:before {
    background-position:-19px 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="germany">Germany country</a>

<a href="#" class="england">England country</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move the class to a span, the background image will display correctly with the text:

```
<a href="#"><span class="germany"></span>Germany country</a>
```

Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/msz6unj5/1/

Answer (score 0):

1) [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hrwk6fu9/9/) Using before and white-space.

```
.germany{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 0px;
    padding-left: 18px;
 }
```

2) [Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/hrwk6fu9/13/) Using container i.e span

```
<a href="#" class="germany"><span>Germany country</span></a>
```